# Duplicate zip entry [allclasses.jar:com/sun/javafx/beans/IDProperty.class] Gluon native android code

Tags: gradle, javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

I am trying to add native code to handle intent actions in android in my Gluon Project .Upon adding dependencies of android into the gradle file and trying to install on android seeing the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':shrinkMultiDexComponents'.
 > java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Vaishnavi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NativeEg\build\javafxports\tmp\android\multi-dex\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Vaishnavi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NativeEg\build\javafxports\tmp\android\multi-dex\allclasses.jar] (Duplicate zip entry [allclasses.jar:com/sun/javafx/beans/IDProperty.class]))
```

build.gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.9'      
        //added
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'


Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
def dalvikSdkHome = properties.getProperty('javafx.dir')
def dalvikSkLib = dalvikSdkHome + '/rt/lib'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'

    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.nativeeg.NativeEg'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:glisten-afterburner:1.2.1'
    //  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.6.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.nativeeg.**.*',
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'com.android.support'

}
dependencies {
    compile files ("${dalvikSkLib}/ext/jfxrt.jar",
                   "${dalvikSkLib}/ext/jfxdvk.jar",
                   "${dalvikSkLib}/ext/compat-1.0.0.jar")
    compile files("${sdkDir}/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.1/multidex-1.0.1.aar")

}
project.tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex) {
    additionalParameters=['--core-library']
}
```

Referred from the sample project's build.gradle  in dalvik-sdk-8.60.9 package

Comment: Why are you adding all the javafxports dependencies? Those are taken care of by the `jfxmobile` plugin. They are added twice, and that's why you get the duplicate error.

Comment: Thanks Jose, removing the following lines : 
compile files ("${dalvikSkLib}/ext/jfxrt.jar",
                   "${dalvikSkLib}/ext/jfxdvk.jar",
                   "${dalvikSkLib}/ext/compat-1.0.0.jar") 
got rid of the duplicate error